# Delete rows based on result of value in concerned row and of other column value in previous row

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, subset

Although there are many questions for deleting rows I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Here is a data.frame as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
             D1 = as.Date(as.character(c("1863-12-01","1945-06-06","1955-03-01","1962-08-01","1980-08-01","1998-12-01")), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
             D2 = as.Date(as.character(c("1923-02-28","1953-05-28","1962-07-31","1978-06-30","1998-11-30","2015-12-31")), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

The result should be without the rows where are more than one day between the date of the row of D1 and the previous row of D2, see this:

```
A    D1         D2
5 1980-08-01 1998-11-30
6 1998-12-01 2015-12-31
```

I tried it by a loop, but it doesn't work in the required way - I have to repeat the loop again and again for the final result:

```
for (i in 1:length(df))
{
  if ((df$D1[i + 1] - df$D2[i]) > 1)
    df <- df[-c(i), ]
}
```

Where is the bug and is there a better way than a loop? Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` u can do

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, D1 - lag(D2) < 2)
```

**EDIT**
In case you want to keep the line where laged D2 fullfills condition use the following:

```
filter(df, lead(D1) - D2 < 2 | D1 - lag(D2) < 2)
```

Comment: After using your code on several data.frames I've recognized that the code deletes every first row of the comparison which normally should stay. Use this dataset below and you'll see what I mean. The filtered dataframe should start with "1955-03-01". df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                 D1 = as.Date(as.character(c("1863-12-01","1945-06-06","1955-03-01","1962-08-01","1980-08-01","1998-12-01")), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                 D2 = as.Date(as.character(c("1923-02-28","1953-05-28","1962-07-31","1980-07-31","1998-11-30","2015-12-31")), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

Comment: I don't understand, why should it start with 199-03-01? The difference to 1953-05-28 is larger than two days.

Comment: @Simon1723 Also, the first entry in `D1` will always be irrelevant, as there is no "previous" entry of `D2`

Comment: @Simon1723 Oh, I think I know what you mean, see **EDIT**

Comment: My aim is to create a continuous time series, so in my last example D1 should start with 1955-03-01 and the time series ends with D2 by "2015-12-31"‌​. Therefore the first entry is also important, and should not be deleted, if there is a continuous time series after it. Sorry, maybe it wasn't well explained by me.

Comment: yes, perfect. It works. There is still a problem, if the dataframe contains only one row, but for that case I use easily an if-else-condition.